# twilio API not sending the repsonse in json format

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I am making an API for sending whatsapp response to client's whatsapp number. I am using twilio as service provider. The problem I am facing is that i am not able to get response in Json. I am following code examples of Twilio

```
const accountSid = 'ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
const authToken = 'your_auth_token';
const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.messages
      .create({
         from: 'whatsapp:+14155238886',
         body: 'Hello, there!',
         to: 'whatsapp:+15005550006'
       })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid));
```

According to API documentation. It should return the response in `json` or `xml`. but it returns an error and error is not also in json. `Socket Hangs up` and then nothing happens. API Reference

[API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource)

**UPDATE:**
After Alan's comment. I have added catch block in my code. But still nothing comes up. The API sends request and then everything hangs. After sometime server hangs and the socket hangs up error is thrown by `postman` console or from Browser.

Updated Code

```
client.messages
      .create({
         from: 'whatsapp:+14155238886',
         body: 'Hello, there!',
         to: 'whatsapp:+15005550006'
       })
      .then(message => console.log(message.sid)).catch(e => 

{console.error(e.error); });
```

Comment: add .catch block to your code and also look at the Twilio Debugger (Bug Icon) in console for errors.

Comment: @Alan Nothing in the debugger. I have checked it. Twilio is sending messge in response it should send json object but nothing comes back in response.

Comment: Not expected behavior. It sounds like you have some type of network connectivity issue to Twilio, in particular if Postman fails.I imagine CURL would fail also - https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360017961894-Sending-and-Receiving-Media-with-WhatsApp-Messaging-on-Twilio-Beta-.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for JSON response from twilio. I couldn't even find in **Twilio** Documentation yet.

- I recommend you to use `try` `catch` block
- And in your `try` block you can add a customized **JSON** response which has a success response with your user defined `header`.
- Default Twilio response will be like below

---

`[Twilio.Api.V2010.MessageInstance accountSid=ACd7c9b4f84efc802cb7bcf8cbeb86b6b9 sid=SMa4d4976f77e844b8a251fcb14e40a855]`

---

- You can **explode** using space(' ') and change to JSON format
- In your `catch` block you can embed `catch error` in JSON format

*I hope this way you can get JSON response*